# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posts' in Django

Tags: python, django

when i run `python manage.py makemigrations`,no module error found occur, plz help me

settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts'
]
```

`urls.py`

```py
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from posts.views import index, blog, post

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index),
    path('blog/', blog),
    path('post/', post),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,
                          document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,
                          document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

`post> models.py`

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

# Create your models here.

User =get_user_model()

class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    comment_count = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```py
(env) C:\Users\Dell\project4\src>python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Envs\env\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\Envs\env\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posts'
```

Comment: Is it called "post" or "posts"?

Comment: Thank sir, after fixing posts to post , it worked !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside `INSTALLED_APPS` you should declare your `posts` like that: `'posts.apps.PostsConfig'` To understand why, take a look at file `apps.py` from your project folder; it should look like that:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PostsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'posts'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, you need a comma (,) after 'posts'

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'posts',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the urls.py file to know if you included the posts.url correctly

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).