# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vote'

Tags: django, django-migrations, django-apps

I'm trying to add apps to my django project and wanted to add in django-vote.  I did so by first using pip to install django-vote (showing that it is installed and where):

```
Requirement already satisfied: django-vote in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (2.1.7)
```

Following the instructions from the github site (https://github.com/shanbay/django-vote), I added "vote" to installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'vote',
]
```

I added the necessary lines to my models.py file, but am still getting the following error when I try to use `python3 manage.py makemigrations`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 91, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'vote'
```

The only other post I've found to have a similar error to mine is [ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'posts' in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833395/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-posts-in-django) but I seem to have all my commas and tried "vote" vs "votes."

What I've tried as well:

- Checking if I have all of my commas
- Uninstall and reinstall django-vote
- Trying another more recent app in case django-vote is deprecated (other apps don't work either)
- Uninstall and reinstall django
- Deleting my migration files and sql file then migrating again

Can anyone tell me what I may be missing?  I have no idea what's going on as everything else in INSTALLED_APPS migrates without a problem.

Comment: The path that you've installed to (`/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages`) is different from the path that Django is installed in (`/Library/Python/3.7/site-packages/`), hence why Django cannot find it. I'm not sure how you installed Django into the latter path. You should consider using a [virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) instead of installing to system paths, to avoid this kind of issue.

Comment: Hmm I thought that may have been the problem but thought a virtual env may cause some more complications so that's why I avoided it.  Guess I may have to do that!  Is there a way to "move" the installation over though and put it where django can see it or point django to where it is?

Comment: Moving package files between environments will cause more problems than it solves. Just create a fresh venv and install all your dependencies afresh into it.

Comment: Wow thank you so much.  I didn't realize I could make and use a virtual environment but leave all of my files in the same place.  I just made a new environment and it worked perfectly!  I'm pretty new to stack overflow, so are you supposed to add an answer so I can hit the check mark or does it not really matter?  Thanks again!

Comment: I would add an answer if I felt it would be useful to others. In this particular case I think there are plenty of other similar questions out there, so I'm going to vote to close this question. This is not to say your question isn't valid - just that I don't think it will add to what is already on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks!